# How to customize the default <option> in a selector

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have created the following form:

```
class ProductFilter(forms.Form):
    price = forms.IntegerField(label='Price', widget=forms.Select(choices=PRICE_CHOICES), required=False)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), required=False)
    language = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProductLanguage.objects.all(), required=False)
```

The default `<option>` in both category and language is displayed as `"------------"`. I know i can set `initial="..."`, but I would like the default option to be something that is not part of the queryset.

Is it possibe to insert an option somehow? I don't want to create a language or a category called "all".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `------------` by setting [`empty_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label).

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), required=False, empty_label='(none)')
```

Note that this value is used when no category is selected. It would be confusing to set `empty_label="all"`.